# Laravel 5.3 Authentication in depence of user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an table hosts and want to redirect to a different page when the user is admin (DB is_admin boolean). 
I use the following Authentication method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/api');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My hosts class:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->is_admin;
}
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this --

Middleware

```
if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() ) {
    return $next($request);
}

return redirect('/');
```

It is because boolean return 1 or 0 which means true or false. So no need to check it wheather it is true by `== true`

Dont forget to add a column in the database with `is_admin` because you are telling to get `is_admin` from the database

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1) {
```

to

```
if(Auth::user()->isAdmin() == 1) {
```

You defined a function, not a property

Comment: Thanks, but it redirects unfortunately everytime to /home even tough the user is not a admin. And if uncomment the code it works also => I really don't know why?!                                                                                                     Is there another method were Laravel 5.3 checks the user creditenials?

Comment: It will only redirect to /home if `is_admin == 1`, check your database

Comment: Yeah, I know but it also redirects if I comment the whole RedirectIfAuthenticated method, any ideas?